# Why my react-admin coasts more than 99% of CPU?

Tags: react-admin

I am new to Reactjs.
I have implemented admin with react-admin, and it coasts more than 99% of CPU and after a while it stops working.

I assume that I made a mistake somewhere but I can not find a way to optimize the performance.
Could anyone advise me to improve this?

I am not sure which code snippet i have to share with you.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you could use the Performance tab on Chrome to pinpoint any bottlenecks in your script. Without more details is impossible to provide any answers.

Comment: Maybe some of your functions calling continuously like **ComponentDidUpdate** in your react application. Try to debug and also check your console window in the browser where you can see the errors.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @SouravSingh
The console says "WebSocket connection to *** failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code:400"
Also, "Uncaught Error: Incompatible SockJS! Main site uses: "1.4.0", the iframe: "1.3.0" at VM67_sockjs.bundle.js:1